# Making audio streaming without RTSP

Tags: audio-streaming, tcpsocket

I'm trying to implement a client/server system for audio streaming. The client should ask the file and the server should send it. Then, the client should play the file immediately. 
I've read some solutions based rtp and rtsp protocols, but they are too complex for my use case. I would like to use a simple file transfer via TCP sockets, but the client should play the audio file immediately, without waiting for the end of the download. is this solution possible?

This is the code I'm using.

SERVER:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ConcurTCPServer implements Runnable 
{
    static ServerSocket listenSocket;
    Socket sock = null;
    static final int port = 12345;
    InputStream recvStream = null;
    OutputStream sendStream = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    String request;
    String response;

    public ConcurTCPServer(Socket s) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
    {
        sock = s;
        recvStream = sock.getInputStream();
        sendStream = sock.getOutputStream();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        getRequest();
        process();
        sendResponse();
        close();
    }

    void getRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            int dataSize;
            byte[] recvBuff = new byte[1024];
            dataSize = recvStream.read(recvBuff, 0, 1024);
            request = new String(recvBuff, 0, dataSize);
            System.out.println("Request for: " + request);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void process()
    {
        //TODO
    }

    void sendResponse()
    {       
        try
        {
            File myFile = new File ("/Users/user/Desktop/" + request);
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            System.out.println("Sending..." + myFile.getPath() + ". Dimension: " + myFile.length());
            sendStream.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            sendStream.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void close()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
            recvStream.close();
            sendStream.close();
            sock.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            ConcurTCPServer server = new ConcurTCPServer(listenSocket.accept());
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            Thread thread = new Thread(server);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import sun.audio.AudioData;
import sun.audio.AudioDataStream;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class TCPClient 
{
    Socket sock;
    OutputStream sendStream;
    InputStream recvStream;
    AudioStream audioStream;
    AudioData audiodata;
    AudioDataStream audioDataStream;
    String request;
    String response;

    public TCPClient(String server, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
    {
        sock = new Socket(server, port);
        sendStream = sock.getOutputStream();
        recvStream = sock.getInputStream();
    }

    void makeRequest(String word)
    {
        request = word;
    }

    void sendRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] sendBuff = new byte[request.length()];
            sendBuff = request.getBytes();
            System.out.println("Sending request for: " + request);
            sendStream.write(sendBuff, 0, sendBuff.length);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void getResponse()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Playing...");
            audioStream = new AudioStream(recvStream);
            audiodata = audioStream.getData();
            audioDataStream = new AudioDataStream(audiodata);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioDataStream);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void close()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
            if (audioStream != null) audioStream.close();
            sendStream.close();
            recvStream.close();
            sock.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final int servPort = 12345;
        final String servName = "localhost";
        TCPClient client = new TCPClient(servName, servPort);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        client.makeRequest("welcome.wav");
        client.sendRequest();
        client.getResponse();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

It only works with small .wav, so I suppose that the file is not actually played in streaming, but it starts immediately after the download. If the file size is around 1Mb or above, the client returns the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: could not create AudioData object
at sun.audio.AudioStream.getData(AudioStream.java:125)
at com.dicet.unisalento.TCPClient.getResponse(TCPClient.java:54)
at com.dicet.unisalento.TCPClient.main(TCPClient.java:88)
```

whereas the server returns the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at com.dicet.unisalento.ConcurTCPServer.sendResponse(ConcurTCPServer.java:70)
at com.dicet.unisalento.ConcurTCPServer.run(ConcurTCPServer.java:35)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Some help, please?

Looking around, I have understood that I need to use HTTP progressive download, but I'm not finding any client/server example implementation using HTTP progressive download.

Comment: Why not stream over HTTP?  There is a lot of existing code out there for connecting to SHOUTcast and Icecast streams which are essentially HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have some links providing client/server example? I only found rtp-based examples for client/server audio streaming.